# validation accuracy not being shown after 1 epoch when using transfer learning from InceptionV3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build an image classifier that differentiates images into pumps, Turbines, and PCB classes. I am using transfer learning from Inception V3.

Below is my code to initialize InceptionV3

```
import os

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
!wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 \
    -O /tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
  
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

local_weights_file = '/tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)

pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)

for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
  
# pre_trained_model.summary()

last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
print('last layer output shape: ', last_layer.output_shape)
last_output = last_layer.output
```

Next I connect my DNN to the pre-trained model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
# Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
x = layers.Dense  (3, activation='softmax')(x)           

model = Model( pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I feed in my images using ImageDataGenerator and train the model as below:

```
history = model.fit(
            train_generator,
            validation_data = validation_generator,
            steps_per_epoch = 100,
            epochs = 20,
            validation_steps = 50,
            verbose = 2)
```

However, the validation accuracy is not printed/generated after the first epoch:

```
Epoch 1/20
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:788: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 4 bytes but only got 0. 
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:932: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
  "Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be "
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 50 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
100/100 - 43s - loss: 0.1186 - accuracy: 0.9620 - val_loss: 11.7513 - val_accuracy: 0.3267
Epoch 2/20
100/100 - 41s - loss: 0.1299 - accuracy: 0.9630
Epoch 3/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0688 - accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 4/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0826 - accuracy: 0.9785
Epoch 5/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0909 - accuracy: 0.9810
Epoch 6/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0523 - accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 7/20
100/100 - 38s - loss: 0.0976 - accuracy: 0.9835
Epoch 8/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0802 - accuracy: 0.9795
Epoch 9/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0612 - accuracy: 0.9860
Epoch 10/20
100/100 - 40s - loss: 0.0729 - accuracy: 0.9825
Epoch 11/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0601 - accuracy: 0.9870
Epoch 12/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0976 - accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 13/20
100/100 - 39s - loss: 0.0591 - accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 14/20
```

I am not understanding as to what is stopping the validation accuracy from being printed/generated. I get an error if the plot a graph on accuracy vs  validation accuracy with a message as:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (20,) and (1,)
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked finally, posting my changes here in case if anybody faces issues like these.

So  I changed the "weights" parameter in InceptionV3 from None to 'imagenet' and calculated my steps per epoch and validations steps as follows:

steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(no_of_training_images/batch_size)

validation_steps = np.ceil(no_of validation_images/batch_size)

Answer (score 0):

As you see ``` WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least ``steps_per_epoch * epochs`` batches (in this case, 50 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset. ``` 
To make sure that you have "at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches", set the steps_per_epoch to:

```
steps_per_epoch = X_train.shape[0]//batch_size
```

Comment: Later, I kept the steps_per_epoch=50. The error mentioned above vanished, but the validation_accuracy was still not displayed.